# How to format image using HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

```css
#r_s_ad {
  width: 12.5%;
  height: 40%;
  background: #FFF;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  right: 0.2%;
  margin: 0%;
  padding: 0%;
}

#r_s_ad img {
  width: 560%;
  height: 150%;
  margin: 0%;
  padding: 0%;
}
```

```html
<div id=r_s_ad>
  <div id="l_s_ad">
    <img src="snetimages/Bop.png" alt="Birds of Prey film poster">
    <img src="snetimages/it.png" alt="It chapter 2 film poster">
  </div>
</div>
```

I've tried using the top property to try and format the image but it doesn't work.
It's part of a cinema website I'm doing for my college assignment. I would like it to be at the top of the div tag but it's being held in but for some reason.

Comment: try adding z-index to image

Comment: "Format" is not really a distinct enough word to understand what you're trying to do. It doesn't help that the images are broken. Please use a service like https://dummyimage.com/ to put it fake images of the correct size.

Comment: div id="l_s_ad", Is that id a typo?

Answer (score 0):

When you say format, I think you are referring to scaling the images to fit the target space.

I changed the id=l_s_ad to a class=l_s_ad in the nested div.
I defined that class in the css.

I then applied that class to the image tags as well.
*(For some reason it wouldn't work for me if I omitted the class from either the parent container or any of the img tags. Not sure why.)

[css]

```
.l_s_ad {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 40%;
}
```

[html]

```
<div id="r_s_ad">
  <div class="l_s_ad">
    <img class="l_s_ad" src="a.jpg" alt="">
    <img class="l_s_ad" src="b.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yh that's what I mean I would like the image to fit into the id

Answer (score -1):

Please provide more information as to how you want to format your images.
I would not recommend your parent div having position absolute or width of 12.5% if you want a big image to be displayed. Also the img width and height should not be above 100%. Please play around with those values in the snippet below. Hope that helps.

```css
#r_s_ad{
        width: 100%;
        height: 40%;

        background:#FFF;

        /*position: absolute;*/
        top:20%;
        right:0.2%;

        margin:0%;
        padding:0%;
    }
    #r_s_ad img{
        width:100%;
        height:100%;

        margin:0%;
        padding:0%;
    }
```

```html
<div id=r_s_ad>
    <div id="l_s_ad">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random" alt="Birds of Prey film poster">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random" alt="It chapter 2 film poster">
    </div>
</div>
```